# set background to Edittext not working fine

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout

I Used edittext in TextInputLayout like below code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilVoucherNo"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imgVoucher"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editVoucher"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/default_edittext_line"
                android:hint="@string/xml_packages_voucher_input_hint"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

with this dependecies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

[image]

but when i want to set background to edittext in error status its become like below image: 
[image]

i tried two solution for changing edittext background:

```
editVoucher.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.edittext_error_inactive_line), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

and

```
editText.setBackground(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.error_edittext_line));
```

that `error_edittext_line` is:

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:top="-10dp"
    android:left="-10dp"
    android:right="-10dp"
    android:bottom="10dp"
    >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/edittext_error_active_line"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I also try below shape for `error_edittext_line` but has same bug:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:right="-10dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:top="-10dp" android:left="-10dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/edittext_error_active_line" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Try to change **PorterDuff** mode value like: `editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);`

Comment: @DhruvVaishnav show nothing with your suggest code!!

Comment: @Ahmad, had u found any solution, i am also facing the similar issue if you find please share,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476005/textinput-layout-turns-editext-into-red-on-setting-error

Comment: @VikramSingh nothing found yet! :( also if you find anything notify me. tnx :)

Comment: @Ahmad you should try to set the background to the`TextImputLayout`